# How do I pass generic type for java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

My code snippet.

```
public class GenericArray <T extends Comparable<T>>{
   private T[] a;
   private int nElems;
   public  GenericArray(int max) // constructor
   {
       a=(T[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Integer.class, max); 
       //Hard coded for Integer.
   }
}

GenericArray arr= new GenericArray<Integer>(100);
```

This works, As I am instantiating explicitly passing Integer.class. How do I make this as generic ?

Or 
Is there a way to print Type information which passed to GenericArray using ParameterizedType ? (If I get that probably, I would handle using if statements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of type erasure, you need to pass the `Class<T>` as an argument in the constructor, like

```
public GenericArray(Class<T> cls, int max) // constructor
{
    a = (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(cls, max);
}
```

and pass the class in the constructor and **please** don't use a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) when you use it. That is,

```
GenericArray<Integer> arr = new GenericArray<>(Integer.class, 100);
```

Comment: Thank you . Perfect.  Extending this, How Can I print the type class I am printing ?  I have tried System.out.println(((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0].getClass().getCanonicalName());

Answer (score -1):

You can parameterized your class by passing the type like:

```
GenericArray<String, Integer> myobj = new GenericArray<>(“John”,2);
```

Or

Consider the given code in which generic method display(), that accepts an array parameter as its argument.

```
class GenericArray <T extends Comparable<T>>
    {    
    public<T> display(T[] val) {       
    for( T element : val)     
    {             
     System.out.printf(“Values are: %s “ , element);    
    }   
    }
    // Declaring Array
    GenericArray[] intValue = {1, 7, 9, 15};                
    GenericArray<Integer> listObj = new GenericArray<> (); 
    // Passing Array values               
    listObj.display(intValue);
```

Similarly, You can declare a class with two type parameters.